Algorithm graph
I have a question I write something like the following. My task is to count all odd path which connect two different nodes in tree. I tried to do it by bipartite graph, but something count wrong, because I have few path less than in in the answer.
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Solution {

    public int solution(int[] A, int[] B){
        Graph graph = new Graph(A.length + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            graph.addEdge(A[i], B[i]);
            graph.addEdge(B[i], A[i]);
        }
        int x= graph.countPath();
        return x;
    }
}

class Graph {
    ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> aL;
    boolean[] visited;
    int left = 0, right = 0;

    Graph(int nodes) {
        aL = new ArrayList<>();
        visited = new boolean[nodes];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
            aL.add(new LinkedList<>());
        }
    }

    public void addEdge(int s, int f) {
        aL.get(s).add(f);
    }

    public void dfs(int curr, int parent, int distance){
        visited[curr] = true;
        if (distance % 2 == 1) {
            left++;
        } else {
            right++;
        }
        for (int node : aL.get(curr)) {
            if (!visited[node]) {
                dfs(node, curr, distance + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public int countPath(){
        dfs(1, -1, 0);

        return left * (left - 1) / 2 + right * (right - 1) / 2;
    }
}



What is the input format? Given you start with dfs(1, -1, 0) vertex identifiers seem to be starting with 1 but in that case you get N-1 edges for N vertices and need to allocate N+1=A.length+2 elements in graph.aL. For example, given a trivial tree of two vertices, what would be the expected inputs?

Second question and likely the root of your problem: in the same case of a two-vertex tree, what would be the "right" answer? The number of odd-length paths here is 1 but your code is counting pairs of same-colored (same-part) vertices which is 0.

Does this answer your question? Count all odd paths in a tree

Consider at tree T.
Split the nodes into two setsA and B depending on whether they are an odd length or even length distance from the root (you can choose root arbitrarily).
The following holds:
In a tree there is exactly one path between two nodes u and v.
A path has odd length iff u and v are in different sets A and B.
Thus the number of odd-length undirected paths in a tree = |A|*|B|
